# ServiceStack auto query global filter

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm looking at using ServiceStack's AutoQuery feature and I have some basic queries working. However I'd like to implement a global filter since I have a multi-tenanted database, e.g.,

All queries should be appended with the criteria 
CustomerId = Session.CustomerId

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: "Best way" questions are not allowed here. Try reading the rules.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use a [custom AutoQuery base class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#intercept-and-introspect-every-query) for this to append the custom filter to each query, e.g:

```
public abstract class MyAutoQueryServiceBase : AutoQueryServiceBase
{
    public override object Exec<From>(IQuery<From> dto)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request);
        var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
        q.And("CustomerId = {0}", session.CustomerId);

        return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
    }

    public override object Exec<From, Into>(IQuery<From, Into> dto)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request);
        var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
        q.And("CustomerId = {0}", session.CustomerId);

        return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
    }
}
```

Then tell AutoQuery to use your base class instead, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { 
    AutoQueryServiceBaseType = typeof(MyAutoQueryServiceBase)
});
```

Comment: The MyAutoQueryServiceBase example will work, however it'll not provide compile time safety. What if I want a different signature where I want to enforce the type From is of some particular interface, e.g. interface IMustHaveSomeCustomerId?

something like

public object Exec<From>(IQuery<From> dto) where From : IMustHaveSomeCustomerId

Comment: is there a way to only use AutoQuery.CreateQuery to generate a sql expression <T> but have the AutoQueryServiceBase disabled? So that I must provided implementation for all IQuery<From> manually? This may sound strange, but without the ability to provide compile time type safety, I can't just blindingly, do a q.And("CustomerId = {}) as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @Jeff if you want a Typed API with ability to use an Interface have a look at [Query Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#extensibility-with-queryfilters)

Comment: is it a bug or am I doing something wrong, that when doing .RegisterQueryFilter<QueryRockstarsFilter, Rockstar>((req, q, dto) =>, the req is NULL. I'm using SS 4.0.50.

Comment: @Jeff Can't tell please open a new question with all the code you're using.

Comment: @Jeff eventually, there's still a lot of hours left in the US :)